# How to add link to index in songs package?

Tags: songs

I'm using the [songs](http://songs.sourceforge.net/) package, and I can't change the behaviour of `\showindex` to add a link to the song name, not the song number in the index.

As far as I could see, I'd have to redefine the [`\songtarget`](http://songs.sourceforge.net/songsdoc/songs.html#mac.songtarget) command, but I wasn't successful. How can I achieve that?

Example (that assumes that the `songs` package is installed):

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[bookmarks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[chorded]{songs}

\newindex{titleidx}{ind}
\titleprefixword{}
\begin{document}
\showindex{Index}{titleidx}
\begin{songs}{titleidx}
\beginsong{Songname}
\beginverse
Song \[C]with chords
\endverse
\endsong
\end{songs}

\end{document}
```

Then, if that is saved in `mwe.tex`, you have to run:

```
$ pdflatex mwe.tex
$ songidx ind.sxd
$ pdflatex mwe.tex
```

Comment: Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Done. Thanks for the tip =]. I believe that example represents the situation.

Comment: I couldn't find the songs package.  I did find songbooks (2010) and leadsheets (2015).

Comment: Songs package: [http://songs.sourceforge.net/](http://songs.sourceforge.net/)

Answer (score 2):

The songs package does not natively support that functionality because, in general, the right-hand-side of any index entry might refer to multiple songs.  This is less common in title indexes than in other indexes, but still happens occasionally.  For example, in a book with three songs all entitled "You", the index entry looks like:

You.....3, 37, 218

The package only links the items appearing on the right-hand-side, since only those are guaranteed to have unique referents.

Changing this behavior entails redefining the internal package code's `\SB@ellipspread` macro, which typesets ellipsis lines.  (Redefining `\songtarget` won't help you; that just creates the invisible destination marker to which hyperlinks point, not the links that point to them.)  The following code (tested on songs version 2.18) successfully links the left-hand-sides of index entries that have exactly one referent on their right-hand-sides, but leaves left-hand-sides of other entries unlinked.  I can't guarantee that it will work in all possible situations, since right-hand-sides of indexes could conceivably contain anything.  But it works for the sample book I tested.

```
\newcommand\savetarget[2]{%
  \gdef\mytarget{#1}%
  \def\songlink##1##2{\global\let\mytarget=\relax}%
}
\newbox\dummybox
{\makeatletter
 \global\let\oldellipsis=\SB@ellipspread
 \gdef\SB@ellipspread#1#2{%
   \global\let\mytarget=\relax
   {\let\songlink=\savetarget
    \setbox\dummybox\hbox{#2}}%
   \oldellipsis{\ifx\mytarget\relax#1\else\songlink{\mytarget}{#1}\fi}{#2}%
 }
}
```